# how to parse below string 2 arrays

Tags: json

I need to parse the below json string please help how to parse
I have 2 array.

```
[{"BuyerHeatMap":{"BuyerId":"1022","Region":"Asia","SupplierCount":9,"Color":"#fff302"}},{"BuyerHeatMap":{"BuyerId":"1022","Region":"Europe","SupplierCount":100,"Color":"#de930a"}}]
```

Comment: Parse with/into what? How you parse will depend upon what language and environment you are targeting. Javascript: `JSON.parse(X)`, Python `import json; json.loads(X)` where X refers to the string.

Comment: Sorry I missed it , its Javascript, When i parse i get [object] [object ]  when i loop